# Datagridview filter using TextBox value

Tags: c#, datagridview, filter

I want to filter Datagridview row using TextBox value, i tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
private void CherchetextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("codeArticleDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1 like '%{0}%'", CherchetextBox.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''") );

        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

So where is the problem in my code??

Comment: Is this the column name of the datatable `codeArticleDataGridViewTextBoxColumn1` ? I don't think so. You need to give the column name of the `DataTable`, not `DataGridView`

Comment: Thank you very much this is the mistake, it is solved